# Cannot invoke 'UIImage' with an argument list of type '(Int, @escaping () -> ())' error while using didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method

Tags: swift

I was using below `UIImage` `Extension` before:

```
extension UIImage
{
    func scaleImage(_ maxDimension: CGFloat) -> UIImage?
    {
        var scaledSize = CGSize(width: maxDimension, height: maxDimension)

        if size.width > size.height
        {
            let scaleFactor = size.height / size.width
            scaledSize.height = scaledSize.width * scaleFactor
        }
        else
        {
            let scaleFactor = size.width / size.height
            scaledSize.width = scaledSize.height * scaleFactor
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledSize)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: scaledSize))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return scaledImage
    }
}
```

I was using this extension in my `ViewController` like below before:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        let scaledPhoto = selectedImage.scaleImage(640)
        {
            activityIndicatorOutlet.startAnimating()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion:
                {
                    //recognize the image
            })
        }

    }
}
```

but `Xcode` gave an error. Because `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method has changed like below:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

}
```

so, I changed `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method with latest version:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

}
```

and then `Xcode` wants me to change this:

```
'UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage' has been renamed to 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage'
Replace 'UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage' with 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage'
```

I have changed above code like `Xcode` wants:

```
if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            let scaledPhoto = selectedImage.scaleImage(640)
            {
                activityIndicatorOutlet.startAnimating()
                dismiss(animated: true, completion:
                    {
                        //recognize the image
                })
            }

        }
```

Finally `Xcode` shows an error in below code line:

```
let scaledPhoto = selectedImage.scaleImage(640)
```

Here is the error:

```
Cannot invoke 'scaleImage' with an argument list of type '(Int, @escaping () -> ())'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Aren't you just missing a `if` before the word `let`?

Comment: You are right... Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `let` keyword when getting an image from `scaleImage` function

Change your code like below to working it

```
if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

     if let scaledPhoto = selectedImage.scaleImage(100) {

         print(scaledPhoto)
         activityIndicatorOutlet.startAnimating()
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                //recognize the image
         })
     }
}
```